# HTTP method/standard for obtaining a list of files

Tags: http, rest, http-headers

Is there any protocol or method specifically for listing files (or a list of file meta-data) in a directory?

I saw nothing obvious at http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml . The closest I think I could see was `SEARCH` which might be used for this purpose but defined no semantics. Are there no standards based on top of HTTP which allow for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is PROPFIND (http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html#METHOD_PROPFIND)